# How to make "routines" in C++ (no functions)

Tags: c++

Imagine I have some instructions which uses/manipulate many many variables from my scope and that these instructions need to be repetead many times inside the same scope.
Is there any way to encapsulate all them and call them with just one instruction without using functions? 
Example:

```
int main()
 {
 int contador = 0;
 float dato;
 queue<float> cola;
 // a lot of other variables

 RUTINA
  {
  contador++;
  cola.push(dato);
  // manipuling a lot of other variables
  cout<<"Se ha ingresado un nuevo dato: "<<dato;
  }
 ...
 ...
 // something happens
 RUTINA;
 ...
 ...
 // another thing happens 
 RUTINA;
 ...
 ...
 // another thing else happens
 RUTINA;
 ...
 ...
 }
```

Obviously, trying to do this using functions wouldn't result nice (especially if we manipulate many variables inside the routine.

UPDATE: If I use a function outside main() (is no allowed inside), it will work of course, but I will have to send all that variables how referenced parameters... and it would be nearly the same that copy/paste the rutine code each time I need.

Comment: Yes, they are called functions.

Comment: In addition to @immibis ...and they may not be nested in C++ (with the exception of lambdas).

Comment: To manipulate variables inside the rutine, pass as reference or pointer.

Comment: You need to learn C++. It is a very difficult programming language. So you'll spend months in learning some of it, and years in mastering it. Start by reading some [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book, and look into some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site. Months later, dive into the [C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) standard.

Comment: Yes, I thought that, but, how I writed at the end, if I have to manipulate so many varaibles, using functions should be chaos. Is there no another way?

Comment: Write it so that you don't have to manipulate so many variables.

Answer (score 7):

That's a lambda that captures by reference.

```
auto const rutina = [&]()
{
    contador++;
    cola.push(dato);
    cout<<"Se ha ingresado un nuevo dato: "<<dato;
};
```

You use it like this:

```
rutina();
```

But it's generally not a good idea.

Better read up on defining named functions, and pass the relevant variables as *arguments* to such function.

Comment: Technically correct, but are you sure the OP can understand that?

Comment: Whether someone can understand the answer to what they're asking is indeed an interesting question. However, I'm not sure it's relevant. ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cheersandhth.-Alf! But this will only work in C++11, right?

Comment: Thanks for your consideration @BasileStarynkevitch, some day I'll be like you ;)

Comment: @AliRojas: C++11 or later. The current standard is C++17.